# How to build cast app which enable to cast media to non Android TV

Tags: android, casting, google-cast

I would like to develop an app which enable to cast medias like audio, images & videos but cast should work without chromecast. It should directly cast to Smart TV. It should be similar to AllCast app. As I am new with Adroid Cast SDK. So any help with example will help me lot to get started.

I gone through the googlecodelabs sample application but it won't show cast icon. As I think it won't find my Samsung Smart TV.

Please help me to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cast SDK only supports casting to Cast devices, such as Chromecast, Cast for Audio, Android TV, etc. Smart TV's such as Samsung TVs are not Cast devices, and as such, the Cast SDK won't help you with that. To expand support to other devices outside of Cast devices, you need to integrate their SDK's with your app (that should include discovery of such devices); after doing that, you can extend the Cast dialog (the dialog that opens up when you click on the cast icon)to "show" such devices but when you select such devices from that dialog, it is the other SDK that handles streaming to those devices. If you select a Cast device from the dialog, then Cast SDK will handle the casting.

Comment: Than how youtube show the cast icon and find my device and start casting to my Samsung Smart TV  youtube App ?

Comment: YouTube is using a variety of mechanisms to discover and stream content, Cast SDK is one of them but for non-cast devices, it uses other mechanisms.